# OkHttp post retries corrupts DynamoDb database

Tags: android, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, okhttp

I'm using `OkHttp` 3.9 to make a `POST` call in an Android app to update an `AWS DynamoDb database` by triggering a Lambda function via an Api Gateway. I notice that the database is updated 3 times with each call. Apparently this is due to the default retry option for OkHttp.

As I understand it, the retries can be prevented by setting retryOnConnectionFailure to false when building the client.I tried this but still the database is updated 3 times - so the call is still being made 3 times.

Some suggest to handle this behaviour on my server. The problem is that if I handle the issue in the Lambda function, then it means that the api has been called three times and so has the lambda function, all unecessary overhead and cost. Also, if setting retryOnConnectionFailure to false worked and the api was only called once, it means that there is no mechanism to handle failure.

So, why does it retry 3 times even when each call succeeds? and most importantly, how do I stop this from happening so that the api is only called once and then again only if the call failed (i.e to succeed in triggering the lambda function)? Setting `retryOnConnectionFailure` to `false` seems to have no effect.

Comment: Can you share your code of setting `retryOnConnectionFailure` to false? Just in case, I think this is useful link: https://medium.com/inloop/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace

Comment: `Apparently this is due to the default retry option for OkHttp. ` You have not convinced me that okhttp does the post three times.

Comment: @greenapps see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

So I have egg on my face!

There was no problem with OkHttp! After some further investigation I found a call to update the database in the lambda function that I was calling. So this was calling the extra updates and not OkHttp retries!

sorry.